# Accessing CSS in angular component from outside

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

I am working on an angular app  Basically it is an angular electron application. I have components in my application where I access my css files as follows.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './my-app.html',
  styleUrls: ['./../../../styles/app.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

I am trying to separate css files from my angular project and want to access these css files from outisde location. I get one location under programData in ngOninit() and then I append /resources/assets/cssFiles/app.css. How I can use this variable in my component to apply styles dynamically in component?

Answer (score 0):

In angular.json, put that location in your assets array.

Comment: I don't want to give hardcoded path. I will get path of css file from a setting files and I need to use that location. That may be different everythime

Comment: Check out this article, seems like you asking for https://www.vjtechworld.com/2019/09/loading-css-dynamically-into-angular.html

Answer (score 0):

You can reference outside assets, css, javascript etc. by adding it to your projects `angular.json`. Find the appropriate array and add the filepath there -- in this case I would recommend adding to the "styles" array.

The styles will be built into your app when you `ng` `serve` or `build`.

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "options": {
      ... bunch of stuff ...
      "styles": [
        "../path/to/css/file.css
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a different file for each component. How my component will know ok I have to use this css file for this particular component

Comment: If you wanted the styles to be accessible only within the component scope I would recommend you copy the styles into the component css file -- this will make deployment so much easier. If you really _need_ to reference this css from "outside" the project you need to use the `angular.json` method or else run a script to dynamically load the css prior to build. The real issue here is if a component starts referencing css from outside the root project you need to account for that when building for production.